# Python exec(open("file_name.py").read()) access worng variables

Tags: python, variables, exec

I am creating something like shell and server.
Long story and a lot script but, the problem
is then I run `server_main.py` from `server.py`
using `exec(open("server_main.py").read())`;
`server_main.py` try access variables that are
in `server.py`, but it shoudn't. `server_main.py`
have to access variables that are in it self.

How it looks like?
`server.py`  ---> runs `server_main.py`
/|\                                         \|/
 |---tries access `variable1` but tries it in `server.py` not in him self

How it should like:
`server.py`  ---> runs `server_main.py`  <------------------------|
                                            |--> access variable that is in it ->/\

Comment: Besides the question, but why are you doing `exec(open("server_main.py").read())` instead of just `import server_main`?

Comment: That's what `exec` does. The behavior you're asking for is what happens when you use `import server_main`.

Comment: I am not using `import`, because `server.py` will close and some time, but `server_main.py` had to stay on after first execution of `server.py`